# Why does setting my Sublime Text rulers to [79, "lorde"] make it display a ruler at 0 and one just before 8 columns?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I was messing around with my Sublime Text 3 user preferences, and entering `"rulers": [79, "lorde"]` got me a tad bit weird result: two rulers, at 0 and a bit to the left of 8.

After some further testing I concluded that whenever anything other than an int or a float is passed in this list

1. A ruler is set to zero
2. All preceding rulers in the list are divided by around ten
3. All following rulers are ignored

Now, my question is: how can this happen? Surely it isn't intended to work like this, but why would a non-number variable divide all others passed before it by circa ten?

Answer (score 0):

No one can say for sure, unless Sublime's author decides to weigh in (fat chance), as the source is closed. The most likely explanation is that there is not sufficient error checking in the ruler function, as it is expecting a list of numbers. Anything other than that is undefined behavior, and what you're seeing is just some quirk of trying to do math with text.

Comment: Well, I was hoping someone else could've ran into this particular bug before. There's not that many ways to go about parsing a list of numbers, so I'd assume there's a fair chance Stack has at least one person who already encountered this.

Comment: @Underyx - If you're looking for others who may have encountered this, I'd suggest asking over at the [Sublime forums](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum). On a wider note, though, even if other people have encountered it, then what? It's clearly a bug in a piece of beta software, and since the source is closed there's no way we can fix it without attracting the attention of Jon Skinner, and even then there are [many other issues](https://github.com/SublimeText/Issues/issues?state=open) that need to be addressed before this rather minor bug.